# Problem with solve : from trigonometry to polynomials

Tags: equation-solving, trigonometry

I want to solve a trogonometric problem by transforming it to polynomial :

```
eq00[X1_, X2_, 
   X3_] = {Cos[Subscript[\[Theta], 3]] + \[Gamma]13*
      Cos[Subscript[\[Theta], 2]] + \[Gamma]23*
      Cos[Subscript[\[Theta], 1]], 
    Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 3]] + \[Gamma]13*
      Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 2]] + \[Gamma]23*
      Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 1]]} /. {Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 1]] -> 
     X1, Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 2]] -> X2, 
    Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 3]] -> X3, 
    Cos[Subscript[\[Theta], 1]] -> Sqrt[1 - X1^2], 
    Cos[Subscript[\[Theta], 2]] -> -Sqrt[1 - X2^2], 
    Cos[Subscript[\[Theta], 3]] -> -Sqrt[1 - X3^2]};
eq0 = {eq00[X1, X2, X3][[1]] == 0, eq00[X1, X2, X3][[2]] == 0};

solXX = Solve[eq0, {X2, X3}];
X2 = X2 /. solXX[[1]];
X3 = X3 /. solXX[[1]];
XX2[X1_] = X2;
XX3[X1_] = X3;
X00 = 0.1; \[Gamma]13 = 0.3/0.19; \[Gamma]23 = 0.2/0.19;
Simplify[eq00[X00, XX2[X00], XX3[X00

-> {-0.560582, -3.05311*10^-16}
```

I changed the $cos$ to $\pm \sqrt{1-sin^2}$. The sign is in function of what the angle is in my problem.

But as you can see it doesn't give me the right solution.

Could you help please ?

Comment: It might be better for you to use the Weierstrass substitution instead.

Comment: Yes but I don't understand my method is very simple...

Comment: Weierstrass is much more complicated

Comment: But indeed it works

Comment: "my method is very simple" - the fact that you have to worry about signs tells me otherwise.